# Counting results displayed

Tags: php

I would like to know how to count how many people follows someone in Instagram and place the number in a var, Instagram gives you this link:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3/followed-by?access_token=xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

And displays a result like so

```
{
    "data": [{
        "username": "meeker",
        "first_name": "Tom",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_6623_75sq.jpg",
        "id": "6623",
        "last_name": "Meeker"
    },
    {
        "username": "Mark",
        "first_name": "Mark",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_29648_75sq_1294520029.jpg",
        "id": "29648",
        "last_name": "Shin"
    },
    {
        "username": "nancy",
        "first_name": "Nancy",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_13096_75sq_1286441317.jpg",
        "id": "13096",
        "last_name": "Smith"
    }]
}
```

How can I count how many are there and place it in a var, lets say:

```
<? echo "You are been follow by ".$followers." users!"; ?>
```

To display: You are been follow by 3 users!

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to use json_decode to to decode the JSON response, then access the resulting object's data attribute (an array of 'follower' objects), and count that:

```
$json = '{
    "data": [{
        "username": "meeker",
        "first_name": "Tom",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_6623_75sq.jpg",
        "id": "6623",
        "last_name": "Meeker"
    },
    {
        "username": "Mark",
        "first_name": "Mark",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_29648_75sq_1294520029.jpg",
        "id": "29648",
        "last_name": "Shin"
    },
    {
        "username": "nancy",
        "first_name": "Nancy",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_13096_75sq_1286441317.jpg",
        "id": "13096",
        "last_name": "Smith"
    }]
}';
$json = json_decode($json);
echo "You have " .count($json->data) ." followers"
```

## OR

```
$json = json_decode($json,true);
echo "You have " .count($json['data']) ." followers"
```

Comment: How can I add the url? because I try using `$json = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/355362198/follows?access_token=355362198.ab103e5.fd1a74e51a964e5bb18e4ca69d0c9b39';` but gives me a 0

Comment: @mithunsatheesh please be careful when editing answers, top explanation text was removed.

Comment: @dbf: oh. my mistake brother. i am sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting as a json string, you need to decode it using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```
$data = json_decode($string,true);
$followers = count($data['data']);
```

[CodePad Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/USqfMS).

Comment: You missed the part where the users are stored under associative array key "data". :) This will probably always yield 1.

Comment: @TillHelgeHelwig - Yeah just got that while creating demo :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) to create a PHP array from the JSON. Then you can simply do a [`count()`](http://php.net/count) on that:

```
$jsonData = json_decode($yourAPIResult);
echo count($jsonData->data);
```

Be aware, however, that you probably should set up some error handling in case the API did not return a proper JSON string. So something like this might be better:

```
if (is_null($jsonData) || !property_exists($jsonData, 'data')) {
   echo '?';
} else {
   echo count($jsonData->data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `json_decode()` which will return you a PHP array. Then all you need to do is to `count()` all the values in the array with 'data' key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_decode

```
$array = json_decode($str);
```

Then give

```
echo count($array);
```

It will give total count of users

Comment: Nope. It will yield 1. Always.

Comment: $str = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/355362198/followed-by?access_token=355362198.ab103e5.fd1a74e51a964e5bb18e4ca69d0c9b39';

Answer (score 0):

simple way to count entries returned asJSON

```
echo count(json_decode($followers);
```

Comment: And then he'll know if there are any more entries in there besides "data". ;)